# How To use preg_match for - , + , . values?

Tags: php, regex, numbers

I use this `preg_match` condition for matching positive, negative and decimal values

```
/^[0-9,-\.]{1,50}$/
```

But when I enter --34.000 it does not show error, when I enter 34...9868 it does not show error,
what I want is that it must accept only positive, negative and decimal values.

Comment: try your regex with something like: `"..,.,,...,,..,....."` lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this regex `^-?\d*\.?\d+$`
i suppose it however cannot be limited to 50 chars

Comment: yaa its work with 50 chars too  /^-?\d*\.?\d{1,50}$/    thanks 4 ur reply

Comment: @RockDance i'm not quite sure, you can cheat it with 100 chars . 0

Answer (score 4):

Better if you use something like `is_numeric()` if yuo need to check if it's a number.

And your regex is totally broke because as now it can accept even only a string containing 50 dots

Answer (score 4):

As yes123 stated, there are better ways to detect if a given input string is a numeric value. If you'd like to stick to regular expressions, the following might be OK for you:

```
/^-?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?$/
```

*Explanation:*

- match start of the string ( `^`)
- match a possible `-` character (`-?`); the `?` means "not required"
- match at least one number (`[0-9]+`)
- possibly match the whole statement in the parentheses (`(?:...)?`); `?:` means "do not capture the subpattern"

  - a point (`\.`); the `.` needs to be escaped due to its special function
  - at least one number (`[0-9]+`)
- match end of the string (`$`)

Comment: +1, though I would say that the .10 would be valid (i.e. the 0 in front of a pure decimal should not be necessary)

Comment: if i enter -9550.44 then its returning array as  Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => -9550.44
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => -
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => .44
        )

)

Answer (score 2):

You need to split up your regular expression so that it only accepts the characters in the right places. For example:

```
/^[+\-]?([0-9]+,)*[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$/
```

To explain this expression:

`[+\-]?`: This checks for a + or - prefix to the number. It's completely optional, but can only be a + or -.

`([0-9]+,)*`: This allows an optional set of comma-delimited numbers. This is for the thousands, millions etc.

`[0-9]+`: This requires that the value contains at least some numbers

`(\.[0-9]+)?`: Finally, this allows an optional decimal point with trailing numbers.